# how do i transfer files from my pc to a unix account in school?

Tags: unix, file-transfer

I believe Window SCP can do it, but I want to know if there is a command which I can use to transfer a file from my laptop to my unix account in school.

I will be using putty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you'd need to use [pscp](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter5.html) which is part of the putty package

the commands will be

```
pscp [options] [user@]host:source target
```

So to copy the file foo.txt in the directory /path/to/ from the server example.com as user fred to the file c:\temp\bat.txt, you would type:

```
pscp fred@example.com:/path/to/foo.txt  c:\temp\bar.txt
```

I'd rather use [cyberduck](http://cyberduck.ch/) with scp tho, its graphical and a lot easier

Answer (score 0):

The best to do *first* is to ask to your school *Unix System Administrator*. He is the best person to give you the advice on this subject. Right?

If the "U.S.A." ask you to use PuTTy here's an excellent tutorial from GHacks: putty tutorial from *Ghacks*:

*About PuTTy and Tutorials, including a PuTTy Tutorial*

http://www.ghacks.net/2008/02/09/about-putty-and-tutorials-including-a-putty-tutorial/

Comment: lols, i went and i got the "um im not sure, let me check and ill get back to you" answer. i was trying to use ftp but it didnt work, im guessing maybe some security reasons.